# Most significant bit in 2 bytes

Tags: byte, bit

I have got the number 317 saved in 2 bytes (00000001 00111101) and it should be transfered via SPI (serial) to a slave device.

The device expect the two bytes `B11` and `B12`, but in a certain order:

> "The highest bits of the data words are send first and the lowest bits
>   are send last, that is, byte B11 is the highest byte and byte B12 is
>   the lowest byte."

My question is, what do they exactly mean? Am I supposed to flip the bytes itselves (10000000 10111100) or to flip bytes AND bits (10111100 10000000)?

Answer (score 0):

Flip the bytes. Or switch , rather:

```
00000001 00111101

->

00111101 00000001
```

This is known as endianness (which should help you find [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030657/little-endian-vs-big-endian))