# How does char* read this integer in hexadecimal? How is it working in ostream::write()?

Tags: c++, pointers, char, hex, octal

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x = 0x414243;
    cout.write( (char*)&x, 1);
    cout.write( ((char*)&x) + 1, 2);
}
```

The output is:

> CBA

I don't understand what (char*)& is doing with x.

Looking at this ASCII table http://www.asciitable.com/, it seems to me write() is writing 141, 142, 143, in octal... in reverse!

How is char* managing to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030657/little-endian-vs-big-endian ?

Comment: `(char*)&x` is first taking the memory location of x (`&x`) and then casting it as a char pointer `(char*)(&x)`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I have no idea what 'endianness' is and I don't see how it is related to this

Comment: @Alberto endianness determines the byte order used to encode some types of values. As other answers have pointed it, you are likely on a little endian system, where the least significant bytes come first. Perhaps reading the answers from the posted link will help clarify things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII codes for upper case `'C'`, `'B'`, and `'A'` are 67, 66, and 65, i.e. 0x43, 0x42, and 0x41.

It looks like your computer is 32-bit [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), so the octets of `0x00414243` (two extra zeros are for clarity, to complete 32-bit `int`) are placed in memory as follows:

```
0x43, 0x42, 0x41, 0x00
```

This represents a null-terminated string `"CBA"`.

Note that on a big-endian hardware the octets would be placed in reverse order, i.e.

```
0x00, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43
```

so interpreting this number as a null-terminated string would produce empty output.

Comment: I actually read the ASCII table wrong and looked at the codes of lower case 'c', 'b' and 'a' XD

Answer (score 0):

The integer type on your platform is most likely more than one byte or `char`.

Since it is more than one `char` in length, it can be ordered with Least Significant byte first (a.k.a. Little Endian) or Most Significant byte first (Big Endian).

The expression `(char *) x` is a pointer to the first character of the integer.

Thus, it could be 0x00 or 0x43, depending on the byte ordering for your platform (assuming that `x` is 4 bytes in length).