# Using fread to copy data into a struct

Tags: c

I am looking at some old code and I really don't understand it.

There is a header struct

```
struct my_header {
   UINT32 chksum,
   UINT16 ValueA,
   UINT64 ValueB,
   UINT16 ValueC
};
```

Then there is a call to `fread`

`fread(&header, 1, sizeof(header), fd);`

And here is the contents of the file, via slickedit hex view

```
F5010000 3906000 50429178 07000000
14000000 0000000 00000000 00000000
```

Once it is read, I inspect the data in the struct, and it looks like this

```
chksum: 0x00001F5
ValueA: 0x0639
ValueB: 32087556688
ValueC: 0x0014
```

When you compare what the `fread` got to the hex dump, it looks almost correct. But things are in some weird order.. for example, `chksum` is `1F5` but the hex dump is `F501`. `ValueA` is `639` but in the hex dump it is `3906`...

What exactly is going on?

Comment: You're probably on a little endian platform (e.g. Intel/AMD x86). It can be confusing when you look at byte-wise dumps and compare them with values > 1 byte, as in this case. You just have to learn to read them backwards.

Comment: [Little Endian vs Big Endian?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22030657/694733)

Comment: @PaulR Thanks... makes.. sense. One more tool in the tool belt.

Comment: Nice that ValueB is printed decimal... or perhaps not so nice ;-)