# Dummy output from an unsigned char buffer

Tags: c++, file, char, buffer

I am using a C++ code to read some binary output from an electronic board through USB. The output is stored on an unsigned char buffer. When I'm trying to print out the value or write it to an output file, I get dummy output instead of hex and binary value, as shown here:

```
햻"햻"㤧햻"㤧햻"햻"㤧
```

This is the output file declaration:

```
f_out.open(outfilename, ios::out);
if (false == f_out.is_open()) {
    printf("Error: Output file could not be opened.\n");
    return(false);
}
```

This is the output command:

```
xem->ReadFromPipeOut(0xA3, 32, buf2);
f_out.write((char*)buf2, 32);
//f_out << buf2;
```

"xem" is a class for the USB communication. ReadFromPipeOut method, reads the output from the board and stores it on the buffer buf2. This is the buffer definition inside the main:

```
unsigned char buf2[32];
```

Comment: What makes you think it's "dummy" output?

Comment: In fact it seems to be correct when you look at the binary format of the string. however, the output binary is reversed. please see the other comments for more info about the behaviour of the output functions. Thanks

Comment: I read them - I'm trying to teach you not to think of unexpected output as "dummy" output :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you expect hex output? You ask to write `char`s, it writes `char`s.

To output hex values, you can do this:

```
f_out << std::hex;
for (auto v : buf2)
    f_out << +v << ' ';
```

To get numbers in the output, values should be output as integers, not as characters. `+v` converts `unsigned char` into `unsigned int` thanks to [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion). You can be more explicit about it and use `static_cast<unsigned int>(v)`.

```
unsigned char buf[3] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56};
std::cout << std::hex;
for (auto v : buf)
    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(v) << ' ';
// Output: 12 34 56
```

To output numbers as binary:

```
for (auto v : buf)
    std::cout << std::bitset<8>(v) << ' ';
```

(no need for `std::hex` and `static_cast` here)

To reverse the order:

```
for (auto it = std::rbegin(buf); it != std::rend(buf); ++it)
    std::cout << std::bitset<8>(*it) << ' ';
```

Note that the order of bytes in a multi-byte integer [depends on endian-ness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030657/little-endian-vs-big-endian). On a little-endian machine the order is reserved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I am not expecting hex, the output is simply binary but I was a bit shocked by the output. I want to read the same binary output without any changing by converting. Is there a way to print the output in binary? Many thanks

Comment: Also, the output is reversed! Like the input, for example, is: 1  27  31  4 156, the output is printed as 156  4  31  27  1! is there a way to fix this as well? thanks

Comment: I used the following for binary printing:
std::cout << std::hex;
 for (auto v : buf2)
  f_out << bitset<8>(static_cast<unsigned int>(v)) << endl;
However, the numbers are reversed!

Comment: @MHDAnasAlsakkal, the loop itself does not reverse the output, but it might be reversed due to endian-ness, for example.

Comment: yes I mean ones and zeros within each number. As I said, if the output should be: 1 2 3 4, the printed output is : 4 3 2 1

Comment: The order is reversed in `buf2` already. You can reverse the output manually. See the updated answer.

Comment: This is perfect!! It works properly with reversing the bit order. Many thanks ^_^ .

Comment: Thanks a lot for perfectly editing the answer : ) However, I have just noticed that actually the reversed bit solution gets the first 4 bytes wrong! but the rest are correct, any idea?

Comment: @MHDAnasAlsakkal, maybe you need to reverse them in blocks of `N` bytes. But it depends on how data in `buf` is organized.

Comment: In fact on a large data input this effect becomes clear and the data is highly corrupted!  the data is actually organised as 4 bytes numbers. every 4 bytes form a 2's complement number.

Comment: @MHDAnasAlsakkal Then you need to reverse them in `4`-bytes block, I guess.

Comment: When the natural order is used, the output data seems to be exactly as expected. but it is reversed as I explained. However, when the reversed order is used, yes most of the data flipped correctly, but some strange numbers appears! is there another way of getting the reverse done? many thanks

Comment: @MHDAnasAlsakkal It is hard to guess without seeing some example. There is no magic universal way. It depends on how your data is organized.

Comment: with normal order: 
Expect output: 00000000001000101101010110111011
Actual output : 10111011110101010010001000000000
You can notice that the forth byte should be first, third should be second and so on. 

with reverse order:
Expect output:  00000000001000101101010110111011
Actual output :  00000000001000101101010110111011 (same)

Comment: However, the first value is: 00000000000101110011100100100111
which is not expected at all. In this example I set the buffer size to 32, and I move the data on multiple iterations. As the buffer size increases, the data becomes more corrupted. As the size of this example is 32 and every 4 bytes form a number in my data, after 8 numbers when the buffer gets new data, some values are also missing. So, it also hard to explain the behaviour of the reverse method. Thanks

Comment: @MHDAnasAlsakkal, this problem has nothing to do with the output itself. I suggest you ask another question with more details about the problem.

Comment: OK, I'll post another question. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I have got it work by swapping the bytes this way: 
xem->ReadFromPipeOut(0xA3, 32, buf2);
  int i = 1;
  for (auto v : buf2) {
   if (i == 1) { v4 = v; }
   if (i == 2) { v3 = v; }
   if (i == 3) { v2 = v; }
   if (i == 4) { 
    f_out << bitset<8>(v) << bitset<8>(v2) << bitset<8>(v3) << bitset<8>(v4) << endl;
    i = 0;
   }
   i++; 
  }