# How to serialize structure data in C++?

Tags: c++, serialization

I was asked in an interview to serialize data (so it could be stored in a buffer and sent over some network). This is what I came up with -

```
struct AMG_ANGLES {
    float yaw;
    float pitch;
    float roll;
};

char b[sizeof(struct AMG_ANGLES)];

char* encode(struct AMG_ANGLES *a)
{

    std::memcpy(b, &a, sizeof(struct AMG_ANGLES));
    return b;
}

void decode(char* data)
{
 // check endianess   
    AMG_ANGLES *tmp; //Re-make the struct
    std::memcpy(&tmp, data, sizeof(tmp));
}
```

Is this correct? Can anyone give alternate designs? I did not get callback so I'm just trying to learn what I could have improved.

Comment: `std::memcpy()` in C code?

Comment: I meant like general embedded C/C++ code. Edited the question now.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin — does `htonl()` manage conversion of `float` data?

Comment: Given that `tmp` is a pointer, `std::memcpy(&tmp, data, sizeof(tmp));` is wrong; you need `sizeof(*tmp)`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Can you give code snippet of the union part?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Maybe it should be sizeof(struct AMG_ANGLES)) because that's what I want in the end

Comment: That would also work, but using `sizeof(*tmp)` takes the size of the object that `tmp` points at, and it points at a `struct AMG_ANGLES` — which is the same size.  There are some advantages to the `sizeof(*tmp)` notation, particularly when doing dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - floating point data with `htonl` may prohibit the use. I didn't check that aspect -- very good point. IEEE-754 won't like having it's exponent and mantissa scrambled.

Comment: @shortint - rather than providing a `union` example (where you still have the endianness issue on how you encode the floats into the char array), take a look at the `pack754` and `upack754` examples at [Beej's Network Guide](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#structsockaddrman) (about midway down) and the `pack` and `upack` functions that incorporate encoding all types.

Comment: Please don't remove the C++ language tag once there are C++ answers posted. Your edit has now made them irrelevant. I will rollback the changes. If you are only interested in C, then please ask a new question instead.

Comment: Also, serializing in an embedded context and in a PC context are wildly different things. Converting everything to strings would be unacceptable in real-time systems.

Answer (score 7):

> Is this correct?

Most likely, no.

The point of serialization is to convert the data into a form that is completely platform independent - e.g. does not rely on things like endianess or if a `float` is an IEEE 754 or something very different. This requires:

a) strict agreement on the intended format - e.g. if it's some kind of text (XML, JSON, CSV, ...) or if it's "raw binary" with explicit definitions of the meaning of each individual byte (e.g. like maybe "byte 1 is always the lowest 8 bits of the significand").

b) correct conversion to whatever the intended format is (e.g. maybe like ensuring that byte 1 is always the lowest 8 bits of the significand regardless of any/all platform differences)

However; it is at least technically possible that the code is not supposed to be portable and the specification ("agreement on the intended format") happens to match what you ended up with for the only platform that the code is designed for; and therefore it's at least technically possible that the code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There could be lots of improvements, but instead of telling all of them I suggest you to examine into [cereal](https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal) . It is widely used serialization/deserialization library, so lots of keypoints are thought.

Some of my thoughts are :

1. Your code depends on hardware which the program running on because of [alignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object) and [endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030657/little-endian-vs-big-endian). So the serialized data is not portable and compiler dependant.
2. `char* encode(struct AMG_ANGLES *a)` function returns `char*`, it is possibly leaked. To prevent the issue, let `std::unique_ptr<T>` decide its lifetime or wrap it with a class. But get rid of pointers somehow.
3. Templatize your serialize/deserialize operations. Otherwise, you could write same functions for other types.

   ```
   template<typename T>
   char* encode( T* a ) // I leave signature as is, just to demonstrate
   {
        std::memcpy( b , &a , sizeof(T) );
        return b;
   }
   ```
4. If the format is up to you, it is better to prefer human readable ones rather than binary archiving such as `JSON`, `XML`

Answer (score 0):

> can someone give alternate design in C?

The "standard" way would be to use `printf` and `scanf` to create an ascii representation of the data:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>

struct AMG_ANGLES {
    float yaw;
    float pitch;
    float roll;
};

// declare a buffer at least this long to be sure encode works properly
#define AMG_ANGLES_BUFSIZE  ( \
    3 * ( /* 3 floats */ \
         2 + /* digit and dot */ \
         FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1 + /* digits after dot */ \
         4 /* the 'e±dd' part */ \
    ) \
    + 2 /* spaces */ \
    + 1 /* zero terminating character */ \
)

int encode(char *dest, size_t destsize, const struct AMG_ANGLES *a) {
    return snprintf(dest, destsize, "%.*e %.*e %.*e", 
         FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, a->yaw, 
         FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, a->pitch, 
         FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, a->roll);
    // my pedantic self wants to add `assert(snprintf_ret < AMG_ANGLES_BUFSIZE);`
}

int decode(struct AMG_ANGLES *dest, const char *data) {
    return sscanf(data, "%e %e %e", &dest->yaw, &dest->pitch, &dest->roll) == 3 ? 0 : -1;
}

int main() {
   char buf[AMG_ANGLES_BUFSIZE];
   const struct AMG_ANGLES a = { FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX, FLT_MIN };
   encode(buf, sizeof(buf), &a);
   struct AMG_ANGLES b;
   const int decoderet = decode(&b, buf);
   assert(decoderet == 0);
   assert(b.yaw == FLT_MIN);
   assert(b.pitch == FLT_MAX);
   assert(b.roll == FLT_MIN);
}
```

However in bare-metal embedded I try not to use `scanf` - it's a big function with some dependencies. So it's better to call `strtof` itself, but it needs some thinking:

```
int decode2(struct AMG_ANGLES *dest, const char *data) {
    errno = 0;

    char *endptr = NULL;
    dest->yaw = strtof(data, &endptr);
    if (errno != 0 || endptr == data) return -1;
    if (*endptr != ' ') return -1;

    data = endptr + 1;
    dest->pitch = strtof(data, &endptr);
    if (errno != 0 || endptr == data) return -1;
    if (*endptr != ' ') return -1;

    data = endptr + 1;
    dest->roll = strtof(data, &endptr);
    if (errno != 0 || endptr == data) return -1;
    if (*endptr != '\0') return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

or with removed code duplication:

```
int decode2(struct AMG_ANGLES *dest, const char *data) {
    // array of pointers to floats to fill
    float * const dests[] = { &dest->yaw, &dest->pitch, &dest->roll };
    const size_t dests_cnt = sizeof(dests)/sizeof(*dests);
    errno = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dests_cnt; ++i) {
        char *endptr = NULL;
        *dests[i] = strtof(data, &endptr);
        if (errno != 0 || endptr == data) return -1;
        // space separates numbers, last number is followed by zero
        const char should_be_char = i != dests_cnt - 1 ? ' ' : '\0';
        if (*endptr != should_be_char) return -1;
        data = endptr + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I needed to use some google and re-read chux answers to properly recall how to use `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` in `printf` to print floats, that's most probably because I rarely worked with floats.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that, when using memcpy different architectures and different compilers will apply padding and endianness differently. To prevent the padding of the struct you could use an attribute provided by GCC

```
__attribute__ ((packed))
```

Nevertheless, this does not protect you from alternating endiannes.
The code for serializing and deserializing using memcpy might look like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>

struct __attribute__((packed)) AMG_ANGLES {
    float yaw;
    float pitch;
    float roll;
};

//The buffer is expected to be the same size as the T
template<typename T>
int serialize(const T &data,const std::unique_ptr<char[]> &buffer){
    std::memcpy(buffer.get(), &data, sizeof(T));
    return sizeof(T);
}

//The buffer is expected to be the same size as the ReturnType
template<typename ReturnType>
ReturnType deserialize(const std::unique_ptr<char[]> &buffer){
    ReturnType tmp;
    std::memcpy(&tmp, buffer.get(), sizeof(ReturnType));
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    struct AMG_ANGLES angles = {1.2, 1.3, 1.0};
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[sizeof(struct AMG_ANGLES)]);
    int size = serialize(angles, buffer);
    struct AMG_ANGLES angles_serialized = deserialize<AMG_ANGLES>(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer is generally correct, but it could be added that in the case of difference of current and desired (protocol-defined) endianness, resulting array can be reversed. Also, your `serialize` function returns `sizeof` of the input type which user could take directly (and as a constant expression) if they wanted, whereas the output buffer is an out parameter and you write to it in unchecked way, which can result in undefined behaviour if the buffer is too small.

Comment: You could create `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` for appropriately-sized dynamically allocated buffer directly in the function, write to it and return, or even use `std::array<char, N>` to avoid dynamic allocation.

Comment: Also, in `deserialize` there's no need to accept `const std::unique_ptr<char[]>&` as buffer parameter, you could just accept `const char*` to be more general and avoid unnecessary indirection while accessing the buffer. See related [core guideline](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-uniqueptrparam). Same for `serialize` (`char*` parameter) if you want to stick to out buffer parameter (e.g. to be able to serialize into the middle of some buffer).

Comment: Also note that in C++, unlike C, `struct`/`class` definitions/declarations introduce a type name in a namespace where they are declared by themselves, without `typedef`s needed (there's no "tag namespace" in C++). So you don't need to specifically write `struct AMG_ANGLES` to refer to the struct unless, however, you want to be sure that name lookup doesn't find a non-type (e.g. function) with the same name (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612476/3162368)).

Answer (score -1):

It's better to make some kinds of class like std::stringstream..
std::stringstream is not good to save binary data but it works the same way you want.
so I could make some example that works with std::stringstream..

This code implement only for serialization but it also add code for deserialization.

```
// C++11
template < typename T, typename decltype(std::declval<T>().to_string())* = nullptr>
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, T&& val)
{
    auto str = val.to_string();
    std::operator <<(stream, str);
    return stream;
}

struct AMG_ANGLES {
    float yaw;
    float pitch;
    float roll;
    std::string to_string() const
    {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << yaw << pitch << roll;
        return stream.str();
    }
};

void Test()
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << 3 << "Hello world" << AMG_ANGLES{1.f, 2.f, 3.f };
}
```